# How does NSMutableData allocate memory?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, error-handling

When I run the following code, it slowly eats up my memory and even starts using swap:

```
 long long length = 1024ull * 1024ull * 1024ull * 2ull; // 2 GB

 db = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:length];

 char *array = [db mutableBytes];

 for(long long i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
      array[i] = i % 256;
 }
```

If I run it without the for cycle no memory is used at all:

```
 long long length = 1024ull * 1024ull * 1024ull * 2ull;
 db = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:length];
 char *array = [db mutableBytes];
 /* for(long long i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
      array[i] = i % 256;
 } */
```

I can only conclude that NSMutableData is only "reserving" memory and when it is accessed then it really "allocates" it. How is it done exactly?

Is this done via hardware (CPU)?

Is there a way for NSMutableData to catch memory writes in its "reserved" memory and only then do the "allocation"?

Does this also mean that a call to `[NSMutableData dataWithLength:length]` can never fail? Can it allocate any size of memory using swap to get it if needed?

If it can fail will my db variable be null?

In apple's "NSMutableData Class Reference" I have seen only vague sentences about these topics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not so much an NSMutableData issue but a kernel/OS issue. If the process requests a (big) chunk of memory, the kernel will normally just say "that's ok, here you go". But only on actually using it, it is really ("physically") allocated. This is ok since if your program starts with a 2 GB malloc (as you are doing here) it would otherwise instantly push out other programs to swap, while in practice you will often not use the 2 GB right away.

When accessing a memory page that is not actually present in physical memory, the kernel will get a signal from the CPU. If the page should be there (because it is within your 2 GB chunk) it will be put in place (possibly from swap) and you will not even notice. If the page shouldn't be there (because the address is not allocated within your virtual memory) you will get a segmentation fault (SIGSEGV or EXC_BAD_ACCESS kind of error).

One of the related topics is "overcommit(ment)", where the kernel promises more memory than is actually available. It can cause serious problems if all processes start using their promised memory. This is OS dependent.

There are a lot of pages on the internet explaining this better and in more detail; I just wanted to give a short intro so you have the terms to put in google.

**edit** just tested, linux will easily promise me 4 TB of memory, while - I assure you - there is not even 1 TB of total *disk* storage in that machine. You can imagine that this, if not taken care of, can cause some headaches when building mission critical systems.

Comment: It is possible to change the Linux overcommit behavior by setting `overcommit_memory` and `overcommit_ratio`.  In particular, setting `overcommit_memory` to 2 means it will only commit the swap space + overcommit_ratio% of physical memory.

Comment: See also the [overcommit-accounting documentation](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/vm/overcommit-accounting).

Comment: The interesting thing about linux is that `mmap()` (which malloc does behind below the surface) takes a flag `MAP_NORESERVE`, which allows overcommit behavior. However, if you - like malloc() - don't specify this flag, it still overcommits.

Comment: It is clear now. Thank you. I have made some more tests and [NSMutableData dataWithLength:length] ends up calling malloc and malloc is using mmap to allocate memory. [NSMutableData dataWithLength:length] and malloc does never fail when called. Not even when called with NSIntegerMax. The program will fail later with   EXC_BAD_ACCESS when first access is made to the allocated memory.

Comment: I can allocate memory up to 0x7FFDAA104000 bytes (140 petabyte) on my system without failing on the first time accessing it. In that case my system runs out of swap space and asks me to kill a process by displaying the "Force Quit Applications" dialog and saying: "Your Mac OS X startup disk has no more space available for application memory". Strange but it seems there is no use to test the return value of malloc on these systems. Either it fails later on the first time accessing the allocated memory or the user is notified about the problem by the force quit dialog.